# Bootstrap 3 visible-xs class shifting grid

Tags: html, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my html right now. Whenever I view it on a smaller screen, rather than appearing on the far right like it should according to the col, it appears in the center of the screen.

```
<div class='row visible-xs-block'>
  <div class='col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-10'>

    <h3>DFA Rice Blog</h3>
    <h4><a href="archive">Archive</a></h4>

  </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to fix this issue

Comment: Using BS 3.1 ? looks like col-xs-offset-10 is re-added on 3.1

Comment: Using 3.2, I used col-xs-offset-10 elsewhere just fine

Comment: Try using pull-right instead of the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Like it was suggested by Shawn, it's best to just use pull right and set your column the length you want instead of trying to play with an offset.  Something like this should work perfectly:

```
<div class='row visible-xs-block'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <h3>DFA Rice Blog</h3>
            <h4><a href="archive">Archive</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to play nice with the bootstrap col system for some reason. My code works, but only in firefox. in chrome and safari it breaks down

Comment: Can you throw up a jsbin or jsfiddle with your code that demonstrates this? using this example with base bootstrap, it works for me.  It's likely something else you have going on might be interfering...

Comment: I'm not sure I'dd go so far as to say it's 'best', was just throwing out an idea. His code *should* work as-is though, so I agree that a jsfiddle or bootply showing the error would be most helpful.